# website looks horrible in firefox is it because I am using a public dropbox url?

Tags: html, firefox, web, stylesheet, dropbox

I am stumped as to why my styling is so distorted when I use firefox.
The website is http://shehunter.joshmu.com

Could it be related to the fact this site at the moment is being worked on via a public dropbox url?

Font, positioning and background transparency seem to all be wrong.

Works fine in chrome and safari.

---

EDIT-
when i click on the info tab the text is displaced far to the left...
in the 'music' section there is a transparent blue background appearing...

---

UPDATE-
info section solved with position:absolute cheers @sarcastyx!
however still have problems in firefox with it accepting google web font and background transparency problem in the music section of the site.
Thanks for all the help everybody!

Comment: It looks in the same in Chrome and Safari to me? Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: it is firefox that I am having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Chrome and Firefox :)

Comment: ah thats bizarre, I just double checked by downloading firefox 12 and it still displays incorrectly. =( if you click on the info tab on yours is it displaced far off to the right? which version of firefox are you using? thanks heaps! =)

Comment: @JoshMu, for the transparent background on the player you can change the embed URL from: `http://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/v=2/album=223776040/size=grande2/bgcol=ffffff/linkcol=ffffff/transparent=true/` to `http://bandcamp.com/EmbeddedPlayer/v=2/album=223776040/size=grande2/`. That should give you the player with no background colour. This could quite possibly be a bug with the FF rendering of the iFrame. There are font rendering issue with FF that are well recorded.

Comment: @sarcastyx gave that a go, no cigar.  It gives a solid white background... I made sure when I grabbed it from bandcamp that it would be transparent. thats why it includes "transparent=true". cheers for looking in to it for me. sigh. will go see if it is resolved in the firefox beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good in firefox for me. Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: cheers ethanh, it does appear the font displays correct.  which firefox are you using? and if you click on the info tab is the text positioned to the left or far off to the right? thanks heaps!

Comment: Maybe you have some weird setting on your computer/in firefox?

Comment: I am starting to think that may be the case...did a refresh install of firefox however and am still having the same probs. very weird.

Comment: in the uninstall wizard it has an option to purge all personal prefs along with the firefox install. did you do this?

Comment: i'm on mac, appzap'd firefox to remove everything cached and prefs, reinstalled firefox 12 with fresh download, still the same.

Comment: I've heard that firefox 12 has formatting bugs... Just to let you know though, I am on windows

Comment: html5 video could be creating the probs? ill make sure to check on some other comps. thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoshMu, I just tried it on my FF version 11.0 on Windows and I have the problem where the info content is aligned all the way to the right. If the info section is always going to be on the left of the screen then why don't you `position: absolute` the info div to the left?

Comment: @sarcastyx awesome, that fixed that! don't know why firefox was unhappy with margins... site still has problems in firefox with not accepting a google web font and background problems in the music section. thanks heaps though!